# Xcode Not Opening Project After Git Merge

Tags: swift, xcode, git, cocoapods

I recently merged two branches and resolved close to 100 conflicts. Now, Xcode doesn't allow me to open up any of the projects from the project navigator. The only way I could edit the conflicted files in the first place was to click on the conflicts from the Issue Navigator.

[image]

I'm not sure if it's important, but the vast majority of the conflicts occcured in the .pbxproj file and I accepted both versions in all cases. Additionally, my Pods project disappeared. When running `pod install`, I got the following error: [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your Xcode files probably got corrupted/left in an invalid format by the merge. Not much anyone can do without seeing the files themselves. It's probably easiest to just attempt the merge again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, accepting both sides of a merge will create duplicate sections in the Xcode project.  Or worse, invalid sections.

Xcode projects are in the old ASCII Plist format.  You can see that the file is vaguely like a JSON or YAML file, with a basic tree structure.  It is possible for this basic structure can get corrupted if you accept both sides of a merge without paying attention to the contents of the merge.  Make sure that the parentheses `()` and braces `{}` are balanced correctly after the merge.

Another problem is the objects represented in the new property list might not make sense to Xcode.  I'm not exactly sure of the requirements of the file structure since it isn't well-documented, but when I've generated Xcode projects from scripts, Xcode has been fairly picky that I generate the file exactly right.

You can try the merge again and focus more on the structure of the Xcode project, or you can pick one branch from the merge and manually make the other branch's changes to the Xcode project from within Xcode.

Comment: Dietrich, thanks for your response. I'll approve the answer once I try out your suggestions